# Odd return behaviour of std::unique_ptr::get()

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

i encountered some strange behaviour when working with raw pointers and std::unique_ptr.get().
given this example:

```
#include <iostream>
class Car{
public: 
    Car(){std::cout << "car gets created\n"; }
    ~Car(){std::cout << "car gets destroyed\n"; }
}; 

void func(Car* carPtr){
    std::unique_ptr<Car> car = std::make_unique<Car>();
    carPtr = car.get();
}

int main(){

    Car* carPtr{nullptr};
    std::cout << "first check: \n";
    if(carPtr){
        std::cout << "car Pointer is NOT assigned to nullptr!\n";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "car Pointer is assigned to nullptr\n";
    }

//Variant 1: 
//func(carPtr);

//Variant 2: 
//std::unique_ptr<Car>car = std::make_unique<Car>();
//carPtr = car.get();
//car.reset();

    std::cout << "\nsecond check: \n";
    if(carPtr){
        std::cout << "car Pointer is NOT assigned to nullptr!\n";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "car Pointer is assigned to nullptr\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Variant 1 and Variant 2 do basically the same thing: the unique_ptr returns the adress of an object to a pointer and then the object gets deleted. However the output in the second check differs for some reason i don't understand.

The output in Variant 1 is:

```
first check: 
car Pointer is assigned to nullptr 
car gets created 
car gets destroyed

second check: 
car Pointer is assigned to nullptr
```

The output in Variant 2 is:

```
first check: 
car Pointer is assigned to nullptr 
car gets created 
car gets destroyed

second check: 
car Pointer is NOT assigned to nullptr!
```

I dont see the difference. In both Variants im basically doing the same thing. What did i miss?

Comment: What is the point of `func`? It doesn't take it's parameter by reference, so the assignment `carPtr = ...` is basically pointless, because the local `carPtr` variable goes away as it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second "variant"  you assign a non-null pointer value to `carPtr`:

```
//Variant 2: 
std::unique_ptr<Car>car = std::make_unique<Car>();
carPtr = car.get();
car.reset();
```

This makes `carPtr` not a null pointer.

Accordingly the output states that it's not a nullpointer. Which is to be expected on most systems. But since it's formally **Undefined Behavior** to use this now dangling pointer value, even just inspecting it for the purpose of checking whether it's null, the output could in principle be anything. You could even get the dreaded red nasal daemon effect. For example.

---

The pointer is dangling, refers to no object, because the object that it did refer has been destroyed via the `car.reset()` call.

---

In order to create nice Undefined Behavior also for the first variant,

```
//Variant 1: 
func(carPtr);
```

… just change the function signature from

```
void func(Car* carPtr)
```

to

```
void func(Car*& carPtr)
```

which passes the argument by reference, so that the function can change the actual argument.

Now the function call changes `carPtr` to a dangling pointer value, with ensuing UB when you try to check whether it's null or not.

Comment: so its basically just coincidence based on undefined behaviour that both variants print different output?

Comment: No, not coincidence. The UB here is "weak" in the sense that it's not likely to manifest on modern systems. It's a formal thing. But the checking of nullness could create a hardware exception on some segmented architecture. The reason for the output you see is as also explained in the answer.

Comment: @Grundkurs: Not really. You can change your code to get rid of undefined behavior, but the fundamental difference between the variants will remain. That fundamental difference is that the first variant **does not** modify `carPtr` from `main`, while the second variant **does** modify `carPtr` from `main`. UB is besides the point here.

Comment: now i get it, the carPtr-Parameter in the func-method is just a local copy within the function, the original "carPtr" in main() never gets affected by the assignment in the function. However checking a raw Pointer that points to a managed object seems to be problematic because it cant guarantee that the object is still valid, so checking could cause UB.

Answer (score 2):

Your first variant has nothing in common with your second.

In the first variant you create some completely independent `unique_ptr` (local to `func` function), pointing to some completely independent `Car` object. Then you destroy them both. Your `carPtr = car.get();` inside the function is a basically no-op that does not do anything. So, your `func` function is completely detached from anything in `main` and does not affect anything in `main`.

The second variant is very different. Right there in `main` you create a `unique_ptr` pointing to a `Car` object. And then you `get()` a pointer to that object and store it in `carPtr` from `main`. This changes the value of `carPtr` in `main` and changes the behavior of your program.